# Cannot update Ubuntu Touch 15.04 R2 apps on a Nexus 7 (2013)

Tags: updates, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

I'm afraid usual updating process does not work anymore even deleting the user settings for Ubuntu One and adding them again (as suggested somewhere)... There are several updates and it starts to download each update, one by one, and says "Installing", one by one as well; but there is a big "Pause All" button at the top of the screen and a grayed "Retry" button for each update. A bar shows "100%" for each update, but the whole update process is a total fiasco...